# Who came up with the term X-Files in-universe?

Tags: the-x-files

Was the term "X-Files" invented by Mulder (in-universe)? Someone else at FBI before him?

Comment: fun fact: in the *Fringe* universe they referred to the FBI's "old X division cases".

Comment: @MikeEdenfield fun fact: not all facts are fun.

Comment: @randal'thor fun fact: not all fun facts claiming to disclaim fun facts are fun are fun, but that one was

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There's an episode, [Travelers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelers_(The_X-Files)) (S5 E15),  that explains where the term came from, and it stems from before Mulder's time. It was because the "U" file drawer was too full, for "unsolved" cases, but the "X" file drawer was virtually empty.

From then on, the mysterious cases were put in the X File.

Here's the transcript of the 1990 flashback scene where the name was explained by its creator:

> BAHNSEN: I already checked. They're missing but I recognize one of these names. It's in an X-file.
>
> DALES: An "X-file"?
>
> BAHNSEN: Yes, unsolved cases. I file them under "x." (Goes to file cabinet..)
>
> DALES: Why don't you file them under "u" for "unsolved"?
>
> BAHNSEN: That's what I did until I ran out of room. Plenty of room in the "X"s.

Comment: I actually lol'd irl. That's the most awesome reason possible -- *totally* suitable for that particular story.

Comment: It makes sense, then they're not sharing space with the large number of legitimate cases that could be filed under "u" for some name or location involved. What's not clear is why they've got a rigid alphabetic system instead of being able to have a drawer with a word on it.

Comment: That's a humorous justification.

Comment: I hate to be the Devil's advocate here, but what about letters V and W, as they come immediately after U ?